# Java Quicksort query

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, quicksort

In the following Quicksort for characters,

```
class Quicksort { 

  // Set up a call to the actual Quicksort method. 
  static void qsort(char items[]) { 
    qs(items, 0, items.length-1); 
  } 

  private static void qs(char items[], int left, int right)  
  {  
    int i, j;  
    char x, y;  

    i = left; j = right;  
    x = items[(left+right)/2];  

    do {  
      while((items[i] < x) && (i < right)) i++;  
      while((x < items[j]) && (j > left)) j--;  

      if(i <= j) {  
        y = items[i];  
        items[i] = items[j];  
        items[j] = y;  
        i++; j--;  
      }  
    } while(i <= j);  

    if(left < j) qs(items, left, j);  
    if(i < right) qs(items, i, right);  
  } 
} 

class QSDemo { 
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    char a[] = { 'x', 'r', 'p', 'j', 'i', 'd', 'a' };
    int i; 

    System.out.print("Original array: "); 
    for(i=0; i < a.length; i++)  
      System.out.print(a[i]); 

    System.out.println(); 

    // now, sort the array 
    Quicksort.qsort(a); 

    System.out.print("Sorted array: "); 
    for(i=0; i < a.length; i++)  
      System.out.print(a[i]); 
  } 
}
```

would the program run more efficiently if, in the following code

```
if(i <= j) {  
        y = items[i];  
        items[i] = items[j];  
        items[j] = y;  
        i++; j--;  
      }  
    } while(i <= j);
```

,the two <= are changed to < ? Would this then avoid calling the qs () method just to swap a character with itself?

Comment: It really doent matter

Comment: Well you would save some swaps but you can't take them really into account. It is unnecessary to swap equal elements.

Comment: You could always test it yourself by using time stamps and sorting arrays that have many items that are the same beside each other.

Comment: This question is probably for codereview.stackexchange.com. But to the question: That swap won't be a major performance imporvement, but you might want to preserve the original order in equal elements in certain cases, there it might be relevant not to swap equal elements